# String compare in iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, compare, substring

I want to find out whether a given `NSString` or `CFStringRef` contains a certain substring. How do I do that?

Comment: I want to basically identify the extension of the String which represents a filename. PLease advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the NSString class reference. What you want is [pathExtension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/pathExtension).

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString
```

...is your man. For example:

```
NSString* search = @"Where's the manual?";
NSRange range = [search rangeOfString: @"the"];
NSLog( @"Found at %u", range.location );
```

Comment: The questioner has clarified their question to a more specific use case. DarkDust's answer is more appropriate.

Comment: I also wanted to know how to find a substring. So, thanks a lot!

Comment: Slight mistake in your code: change `NSRange range.location =` to `NSRange range =` :-)